# Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'. for google ad

Tags: android

I keep getting this error code when I try to run the app
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Could not find com.google.androids.gms:play-services-ads:19.7.0.
> Searched in the following locations:
> - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/androids/gms/play-services-ads/19.7.0/play-services-ads-19.7.0.pom
> - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/androids/gms/play-services-ads/19.7.0/play-services-ads-19.7.0.pom
> Required by:
> project :app

Possible solution:

- Declare repository providing the artifact, see the documentation at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html
  This is my build.gradle:app file

```
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.dc"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 30
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.androids.gms:play-services-ads:19.7.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:19.7.0'

}
```